# tablesorter sorting number with commas in them

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am having issues using tablesorter plugin for currencies with a , in them
e.g.: 9,789,000.00 etc.

Does anyone know of a work  around for this?

Pls dont suggest me the other libraries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tablesorter allows you to define ["custom parsers"](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html) for things like this.

```
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method 
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'thousands',
    is: function(s) { 
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) {
        // format your data for normalization 
        return s.replace('$','').replace(/,/g,'');
    }, 
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric' 
}); 

$(function() {
    $("table").tablesorter({
        headers: {
            6: {//zero-based column index
                sorter:'thousands'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You may have to tweak the format function.

Also try to search here on the page, the subject has been answered discussed plenty of times like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403726/jquery-tablesorter-plugin-comma-decimals)

Comment: how does the id parameter work...  id: 'thousands' is this a customizable id?

Comment: `thousands` is just the unique id of the parser. Alternative, try to see this [example](http://jsbin.com/equci5)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem, found out that all my columns were considered under id:text, so I modified the formatting like this:

```
format: function(s) {
    s=s.replace(new RegExp(/[^0-9A-Za-z ]/g),"");
    return $.trim(s.toLowerCase());
}
```

Replaced everything other than 0-9, a-z, A-Z and of course the space character.

Took me 5 hours of banging my head against the wall  (quite literally) to solve this one.

Accepting @Jacta's  answer anyways as it was the starting point, before the head banging :)

Comment: You could have asked for more details if you needed, glad you got it working though.